# How to select li child of a ul without nth-child via css?

Tags: html, css

I am getting a problem with my project where our client has used a logo image inside the menu's `ul li`. He has used a class with `li` where the logo is placed but I cant use the class with it; I also do not want to use `:nth-child` because in future we may add a new menu element. I currently have an empty anchor inside the logo `li`. Is it possible in the CSS to select this anchor which is empty. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Client Site: http://www.kangaroopartners.com/about/

My Site: http://kangaroopartners-2.hs-sites.com/test1

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/thwkav0e/

CSS and HTML:

```css
ul {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul li:nth-child(4), ul li:last-child {
    background:red;
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hello1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hello2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hello3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hello4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It seems that that `li` does has a class. In your client's source code `<li class="logo">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:empty` selector should be what you are looking for.

```
ul li a:empty {
    background:red;
    width:50px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thwkav0e/1/